# how to remove the black background when the keyboard appears

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, keyboard

this is my function

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    keyboardSize = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect frame = [self.tableView frame];
    frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;

    [self.tableView setFrame:frame];
}
```

it works well but when the keyboard appears there is a black background that I wish to make white or clear.

before clicking on the edit
[image]

after click while keyboard opens
[image]
[image]

keyboard is open and ready for input
[image]

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

> it works well

No it doesn't. It works atrociously. You need to throw this entire code out and start again.

The problem is this line:

```
[self.tableView setFrame:frame];
```

I can think of many ways to state what is wrong with that code:

- You are doing it *too soon* - in `keyboardWillShow`. So naturally there is a black space until the keyboard *does* show.
- You are not *animating* the change. Animate the change to match the animation of the keyboard.
- Most important: The entire notion is misbegotten. You should not be changing your table view's *frame* but its *content inset*.